# Ubuntu 16.04 showing parent ID 4147 for an orphan process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, process, orphan

So I was trying a code in ubuntu 16.04 to see how orphan processes are taken by the init process, the parent id of orphan processes was 4147 , what is this process? and how can I make the init process take over orphan processes.

The code used and the outcome are in the picture

[image: snapshot of the outcome]

Comment: Have you checked what process `4147` is?

Comment: its name is upstart.

Comment: And that is the standard "init" system in Ubuntu (similar to systemd used in many other Linux distributions). It might be restarted for some reason and therefore get a new pid.

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: Please state the errors. The text on the picture is too small to read. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Since kernel version 3.4 init is no longer the parent for orphan processes